# Ableton Live - Playing back MIDI tracks and freezes, replaying same note forever

Tags: midi, ableton-live, midi-controller-keyboard

So I'm playing a MIDI track in Ableton Live, and suddenly it starts replaying the same note forever.  I've tried hitting stop twice, turning midi learning on/off twice, literally deleting the track, turning volume all the way off, turning the track off, the sound persists, and I can't get Ableton to play anything else.

Happening every few minutes now, renders Ableton unusable.

Help!

Comment: What operating system do you use? It's possible that Ableton Live on some OS's is not as stable. (For other programs such as Finale Notepad, the alternate-OS version may not even be available.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci I'm using MacOS 11.0.1

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a MIDI feedback loop issue. Try the following steps to resolve it:

1. Disconnect all MIDI devices from your computer
2. Quit Ableton Live, restart, and reconnect your MIDI devices one by one.
3. If no joy, disable all virtual instruments and reconnect one by one.
4. If joy is still absent, reset the MIDI preferences